# Softwood butcher-block name?

Tags: composite

I used to be able to buy a lumber product at the big-box home-improvement emporium which was like butcher-block side-laminated panel, but made of soft wood (pine? fir?, etc.)

I would like to make some benches with this material. It doesn't need to be hard-wood like real butcher-block (and I don't have the budget for that, either.)  But I don't know what it is called, and Google can't find it if I don't know its name.

The key-words "laminated" and "composite" are apparently applied to different kinds of things. Laminated seems to mean "vertically stacked" (like plywood, etc.) And "composite" refers to things like MDF, chip-board, etc.  What key word am I missing here?

Comment: When you say 'butcher block', are you talking about something with end grain sticking up, or sideways? (Maybe a picture could help.)

Comment: Thanks,  I hadn't thought about it (because it isn't important in this application), but now that I look at it, the train is sideways, not on edge like a true butcher-block.  I will grab a photo.

Comment: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Edge-Glued-Panel-Common-21-32-in-x-18-in-x-4-ft-Actual-0-656-in-x-17-25-in-x-48-in-493554/202017000 (edge glued panel/ edge laminated board is probably the terms you want)

Comment: Thank you!   "edge glued" was the key word!  If you put that into an answer, I will mark it as accepted.  Alas, not stocked within 100 miles of Portland Oregon, and only the larger widths can be shipped for pick up. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

For any future searches, here's an [example product](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Edge-Glued-Panel-Common-21-32-in-x-18-in-x-4-ft-Actual-0-656-in-x-17-25-in-x-48-in-493554/202017000).

"Edge glued panel" or "edge laminated board" are probably the best search terms.